# Drawbacks of Microsoft Identity Manager MIM

Tags: access-token, identity, claims-based-identity

I am trying to evaluate Microsoft Identity Manager and try to understand it both from a functionality point of view. I know that Microsoft has released service Pack which covers PIM. But Which functionality doesn't MIM stil cover?

My other question is how the authentication part of MIM work? 
Is it possible to use ADFS with MIM?

I appreciate all kind of advice.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, the article https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/iamsupport/2017/03/27/using-microsoft-identity-manager-2016-sp1-portal-self-service-password-reset-with-web-application-proxy/ describes how to configure the web application proxy and ADFS in front of the MIM Portal to map users to Windows AD identities, and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-identity-manager/working-with-mim-certificate-manager for the users of the virtual smartcard management client authenticating with ADFS prior to communicating with MIM CM.